# Is it necessary to use Stunnel while using Postfix with Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix, amazon-ses, stunnel

I have configured AWS SES with postfix to send emails. Is it necessary to use Stunnel while using Postfix 3.1.0 with AWS SES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your *postfix* to submit emails to SES **using TLS** and you don’t need *stunnel*.

See [Configuring TLS in Postfix SMTP client](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_levels). Make sure you follow the Postfix SMTP *client* configuration as your postfix acts as a *client* submitting emails to SES *server*.

Hope that helps :)